# How to bind DVWA to a real available ip in my network?

Tags: docker, security, penetration-testing, security-testing

I started messing with docker and [DVWA](https://github.com/digininja/DVWA), I've noticed that the docker DVWA's enviroment is binded to the localhost (127.0.0.1). I wanted to bind it to a real address in order to mess with it from another machine but keeps outputting the following error:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -p 192.168.0.103:80:80 vulnerables/web-dvwa
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint epic_nightingale (8c5df17c4fd03285279064b1bcb4a355327367fdf92aab639d2584869e76e5c2): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 192.168.0.103:80: bind: cannot assign requested address.
```

I verified that the assigned ip wasn't being used and the port as well. Finally I just wanted to know if what I'm trying to do is even possible and if so how can I achieve it?

Comment: Is the `192.168.0.103` address already configured on one of your host's interfaces?

Comment: @DavidMaze I mean I’ve made arp requests and checked what ip’s are connected to the network and so far seems not being used by any device

Comment: Docker won't reconfigure the host's network interfaces.  If the host doesn't already have that IP address then `docker run -p` won't bind to it, with pretty much exactly that error.

Comment: (Please make sure your questions are actually about programming, as described in the [help/on-topic].  This might be better asked on another Stack Exchange site with a different focus, like [unix.se], [devops.se], or [sf].)